# CSV files cant store special characters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, encoding, csv, special-characters

I have read several other questions on this subject but none have an answer which fixes my problem.

I have an execel file which is in russian and I need to convert it to CSV without it losing any of the special characters because at the moment it just converts them to "?"

So far after reading similar questions I have tried:

- saving to from .xlsx to .xls and then to .csv with no luck
- importing the spreadsheet into google spreadsheets and downloading as
  .csv with no luck
- downloading OpenOffice and trying to save it as CSV using Calc with
  no luck
- Changing the encoding within excel when you saveit, going into web
  options. with no luck
- opening it up in notpadd++ and encoding it as ANSI as well as other
  types with no luck.

could someone help me out here is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I think what is important here is not just that it is a `.csv` file but the program that you are using to open it.Now, Microsoft Excel uses `UTF-16` encoding while most other applications that open `.csv` files use `UTF-8`. I have had issues previously with `UTF-8` encoded `.csv.` files not being treated properly in Excel (special characters) but other clients being able to handle them okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known issue with saving CSV files in excel, and I do not believe it is possible to solve directly. However an addon such as [this](http://jaimonmathew.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/excel_addin_to_work_with_unicode_csv/) one (includes source) can be used to get around the issue.

> **How does it work?**
>
> As Excel can handle Unicode text (*.txt) files perfectly well, I’m relying on that to make this Addin work. On save, this Addin will be calling Excel’s SaveAs method to create a temporary Unicode Text file. It will then overwrite the original file by replacing all Tabs with comma and reload it. As it is a CSV file, Excel doesn’t preserve any column width adjustments or last active cell. Currently this Addin will reset the last active cell, and I think it should be pretty straightforward to reset column widths as well, if you wish to do so.